# Setting KRB5_CONFIG is thread safe?

Tags: c++, ldap, kerberos, mit-kerberos, mod-auth-kerb

I need to set the path of krb5.conf in my code.
Please Let me know which is thread safe ?

Method 1: 
Set the Environment variable like

```
setenv("KRB5_CONFIG" ,"/etc/krb5.conf",1);
```

Method 2:(I am not sure whether this will set the krb5.conf file path)

```
krb5_set_config_files(krb5_context context,char **filenames);
```